# How do you use QLPreviewController?

Tags: iphone, quicklook

This looks like the best way to so a preview of documents but I can't find any information on how to use it. Am I missing something or is there a better way to do this?

http://developer.euro.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops... I just needed to restart Xcode. My problems were all solved after closing and reopening Xcode.